# What does maxBufferSize="-1" mean in Mule?

Tags: asynchronous, mule, mule-esb

I saw this configuration in existing code and I wonder what does maxBufferSize="-1" mean as I haven't seen any other examples in the Internet apply a negative value to this attribute. Can anyone explain please?

```
<asynchronous-processing-strategy name="AsynchronousProcessingStrategy" maxThreads="${MAX.PARALLEL.PROCESS}" minThreads="1" threadTTL="30000" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" threadWaitTimeout="-1" maxBufferSize="-1" doc:name="Asynchronous Processing Strategy"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/flow-processing-strategies:

`maxBufferSize` determines how many requests are queued when the pool reaches maximum capacity and the pool exhausted action is WAIT. The buffer is used as an overflow.

-1 would be an infinite number of requests.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if it means infinite. If maxBufferSize is used, do we still need to put poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"? Just curious.

Comment: Not sure. You could test, the maxBufferSize is optional according to the documentation.